# Trying to make a pause/resume music activity using service

Tags: android, service

I'm trying to create an activity with one button in its layout which will pause or resume the music when it's pressed. the problem is that when it's pressed to resume the music it starts the audio file all over again. Any idea how to make it play from the last point it stopped rather than restarting it?

**Main activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private Boolean isMusicPlaying;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        View musicButton = findViewById(R.id.music_button);
        musicButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MusicService.class));
        isMusicPlaying = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.music_button)
            if (isMusicPlaying) stopService(new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                    MusicService.class));
            else startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MusicService.class));
        isMusicPlaying = !isMusicPlaying;
    }
}
```

**Service class**

```
public class MusicService extends Service {

    MediaPlayer player;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song);
        player.setLooping(true); // Set looping
        player.setVolume(100, 100);
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        player.start();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        player.pause();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like MediaPlayer object in your service is not kept when you stop the service.
You can get the current position of your song using getCurrentPosition() method before you stop your service,

```
player.pause();
currentPos = player.getCurrentPosition();
```

and send this value back to activity before it is stopped.

Then, you can use seekTo(int) method to move to specified time position before playing.

```
player.seekTo(currentPos);
player.start();
```

For communication between your service and activity, you might register broadcastreceiver and communicate using intent or use a [bound service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html).

UPDATE:
I found following tutorial and you'd better to follow this. It's about using a service with MediaPlayer.
Especially, you are not using prepare method at all when you initialize your MediaPlayer. put these lines:

```
player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
player.prepareAsync();
```

and add listener:

```
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {
    player.start();
}
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#mpandservices

Comment: Did you get the right current position from the service and it's not working?

Comment: When I declared currentPos I gave it a value of 10000 so the music will start 10 seconds into the song but it didn't work.

Comment: Whenever you stop and re-start your service, onCreate method is called  so make sure you are passing the right value to the activity from your service and setting that value to the mediaplayer when restarting.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that the activity is re-started why don't you save the states to Shared Preferences